# Variable redefinition warning

Tags: ruby

I got warning in the following code:

```
while true
  10.times { print "-"}
  puts "-"
  print "Температура по Цельси: "
  C = gets.to_i
  if (C < -273.15)
    print "Ошибка: температура меньше абсолютного нуля\n"
  else
    print "Температура: #{C + 273.15} по Кельвину\n"
  end
end
```

When running, I get:

```
test.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant C
test.rb:7: warning: previous definition of C was here
```

How can I redefine it without error? Why is it defined as a constant and not a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it defined as a constant and not a variable?

Because `C` starts with a capital.

> How can I redefine it without error?

Use a local variable, which starts with small letter, for example: `c`.

Comment: @Gavriel Thanks for the edit, but a non-restrictive (adverbial) relative clause should be used in this case.